# Are these pineapple seeds starting to germinate?

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy, fruit

What is this? Is it the structure from where pineapple seeds grow? The photo is a slice of fruit.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Never seen anything like that inside a pineapple, but it vaguely resembles an inflorescence (grouping of flowers). However it isn't clearly like what is expected for a bromeliad. I'm skeptical that you can get an answer here with this picture. Did you keep this structure and is there any chance you get clearer pictures — ideally using an SLR camera with a macro lens, but borrowing different models of cell-phones might also help (assuming that is what you used). Alternatively, do you have access to an institution with botanists on staff and a dissection microscope?

Comment: @tyersome sorry I didn’t keep it. But I understand the limitations of what I’m asking based on this photo only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Is it the structure from where pineapple seeds grow?**

Yes, these are pineapple ovules, which if properly fertilized would develop into seeds.* The structure they're attached to is the placenta, which is found inside a chamber called the locule. In pineapples, three locules together form an ovary. Pineapples are interesting in that the whole fruit is made up of dozens of ovaries all grouped together, each one with a flower facing the outside of the fruit.

See [this blog post](https://botanistinthekitchen.blog/2017/12/14/a-holiday-pineapple-for-the-table/) for a good explanation of what's going on.

**Are these pineapple seeds starting to germinate?**

No, these have not been fertilized. To germinate the ovule would need to be fertilized, mature into a seed, and then be planted in the right environment for the embryo to continue development.

---

*Commercial pineapples don't generally produce seeds because pineapples require genetically distinct pollen for fertilization. Commercial pineapples are propagated from cuttings because it's faster and more reliable than trying to obtain seeds.

Comment: Awesome answer, thanks! This pineapple did have seeds.